# Howto inject the right instance of a single type into another class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I've got two [typed HttpClients](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#typed-clients) that get a configuration class injected:

```
public class MyConfig
{
    prop string Prop { get; set; }
}

public class MyConfig2
{
    prop string Prop { get; set; }
}

public class HttpClientService
{
    public HttpClientCoreService(HttpClient client, IOptions<MyConfig> config)
    {
    }
}

public class HttpClientService2
{
    public HttpClientCoreService2(HttpClient client, IOptions<MyConfig2> config)
    {
    }
}
```

As you can see the classes are basically identical, just the configuration isn't.

```
services.Configure<MyConfig>(x =>
{
    x.Prop = "x";
}

services.Configure<MyConfig2(x =>
{
    x.Prop = "y";
}

services.AddHttpClient<HttpClientService>();
services.AddHttpClient<HttpClientService2>();
```

I'd like to have just one config and one service but therefore I need some DI magic (if possible) to happen. 

I somehow need to tell the DI which version of MyConfig should be injected for the specific instance of HttpClientService (this should be possible if I use named HttpClients).

Is this possible?

Comment: What are the criteria for using client1 or 2? Because sadly there needs to be some logic behind "magic" when it comes to programming

Comment: If it's up to the classes getting them injected to specify then you might be looking at something using generics so you get a `HttpClientService<TGenericType>` and a `MyConfig<TGenericType>` where the `HttpClientService<TGenericType>` asks for the `MyConfig<TGenericType>` in it's constructor

Comment: If I use named clients I can register them: services.AddHttpClient<HttpClientService>("One") and retrieve them via factory clientFactory.CreateClient("One") so the classes getting them injected could specify which one to get injected. The problem is the configuration - I need to connect the right one in startup somehow - how do I do this?